# MySQL syntax error on SET when defining a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I can't figure out why this trigger creation syntax fails:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.col1 = 0 AND NEW.col2 != '' AND NEW.col3 > 0 THEN
        SET NEW.col1 = NEW.col3 - (10 * 60);
    END IF;
END;
```

MySQL says there's a syntax error at line 5, just before/on the SET statement. I'm using MySQL 5.0.27. I can't see what's wrong, seeing as it's pretty much identical to the example given [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) 3/4s down.

PS: I'm entering this in the SQL tab on PhpMyAdmin. Adding "delimiter" statements doesn't help. Any clues? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks fine to me, other than the delimiter. Line 5 is the first semicolon, which again says "delimiter" to me, but given your P.S. I won't post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Apparently PhpMyAdmin ignores MySQL's delimiter command when entered as part of an SQL query. Instead, you need to set the delimiter in a separate form field below the SQL query. I totally missed that!